# I want to know How to parse the file in OWL/XML syntax

Tags: semantic-web, owl, owl-api

I don't know how to parse this file, can someone tell me how to parse it?
The file is on the below. I have tried to find the way to parse for about 3 days.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>


<!DOCTYPE Ontology [
    <!ENTITY owl "http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#" >
    <!ENTITY xsd "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#" >
    <!ENTITY owl2xml "http://www.w3.org/2006/12/owl2-xml#" >
    <!ENTITY rdfs "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#" >
    <!ENTITY ontology_people1 "http://www.okkam.org/ontology_people1.owl#" >
    <!ENTITY rdf "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" >
]>


<Ontology xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2006/12/owl2-xml#"
     xml:base="http://www.w3.org/2006/12/owl2-xml#"
     xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
     xmlns:owl2xml="http://www.w3.org/2006/12/owl2-xml#"
     xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
     xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
     xmlns:ontology_people1="http://www.okkam.org/ontology_people1.owl#"
     URI="http://www.okkam.org/ontology_people1.owl">
    <SubClassOf>
        <Class URI="&ontology_people1;Address"/>
        <Class URI="&ontology_people1;Location"/>
    </SubClassOf>
    <Declaration>
        <Class URI="&ontology_people1;Address"/>
    </Declaration>
   ......
</Ontology>



<!-- Generated by the OWL API (version 2.2.1.1138) http://owlapi.sourceforge.net -->
```

Comment: @Ignazio Excuse me. Do you how to do it?

Comment: Why can't you use the OWL API ???

Comment: What's wrong with http://owlapi.sourceforge.net/ According to that, the OWL API includes several parsers for OWL XML.

Comment: There are many (very many) different ways to parse this data, and the best way depends on what you want to do with the information. To advise you we really need to know WHY you are parsing it. It's also helpful to know what programming language you are working in (Java, C#, Javascript?) as this is also very likely to affect the choice.

Comment: Thanks for all of you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be parsed with the default parsers loaded by OWLAPI.

This should be enough:

```
import java.io.File;

import org.semanticweb.owlapi.apibinding.OWLManager;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLOntology;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLOntologyCreationException;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLOntologyManager;

public class Check {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws OWLOntologyCreationException {
        OWLOntologyManager manager=OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager();
        OWLOntology o=manager.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(new File("filename.xml"));
    }
}
```

Comment: I also has a question. How to traverse it ? I can't find how to traverse it in your tutorial on the github.

Comment: o.getAxioms() will give you all axioms declared in the ontology.

Answer (score 0):

Don't get frustrated. I think you are looking for an xml parser. Which language are you using? There are already many xml parser implemented by other people. Here is an example using Java: https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/

Comment: Let me have a try. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, it didn't work. Maybe this is not the tool I want.

Comment: This is OWL/XML, not just XML. The OP is looking for a parser that will extract an OWL ontology from this input - more specific than a general XML parser.

Comment: Hi @Ignazio I am trying to build Golang module to parse OWL/XML. Porting the code from Java library under owlcs/owlapi is probably the hard way. From where do I start?

Comment: @Ignazio my focus is only OWL/XML for now.

Comment: @Fahad depends on the scope of the parser output. Best to port owlcs/owlapi/parsers/../owlxml/parser. Please create a new question or an issue on the OWLAPI tracker for more details.